# Is it possible to read/get a line of the console log in javascript?

Tags: javascript, logging, console, console.log

I'm trying to read and store a console log line in a variable , but don't know whether this is possible.

In example.js

```
console.log("123"); 
console.log("456"); 
console.log("789");
```

I want to read out the last console line, and store this variable.

```
let consoleLine = ...; //Should be "789"
```

Is there a way to do this? And I don't want to use stored variables along the lines of

```
let line = "789";
console.log(line);
```

It's specifically reading the console line and storing that in a variable.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: The console API is not standardized. If there is such a thing it will be browser specific. But you can always override `console.log` and implement such a functionality yourself.

Comment: You can overwrite `console.log` so that it also stores the last written thing into a location where you can access it again, but that's weird. Why do you think you need this, what is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: My actual problem is that I'm using Webassembly to print something to the console, and I don't know how to get that variable from Wasm into Javascript. Reading the console seemed the easier step